# "And" to continue evaluation after "False"

Tags: evaluation, boolean-computation

Below, is it possible to print `No` and have x be 2. That is, I'm looking for an `And`-like function that looks at all arguments before returning.

```
x := 1
If[And[True, False, True, False, (x := 2; True)], Print["Yes"], Print["No"]]; x
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `And` and still get what you want:

```
x := 1
If[And @@ {True, False, True, False, (x := 2; True)}, Print["Yes"], Print["No"]]; 
x

(* No
   2 *)
```

What happens is that the `List` and its arguments are evaluated before `And` is applied to it, hence setting the value of `x`.